# Sharepoint - UserProfile.PersonalSite is null for couple of users

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I am trying to get Public URL of all my sites. i have ran this code for every loginname and its working fine except for one user. for this user i am getting null in up.PersonalSite. i have checked it manually and mysite for that user exists. any ideas why up.personalsite is returning null. any suggestions?

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(Site);
UP.UserProfileManager upm = new UP.UserProfileManager(context);
UP.UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(LoginName);
 if (up.PersonalSite == null)
    return "#";
 else
    return up.PublicUrl.OriginalString;
```

Comment: also i noticed in central administration that i have site collection for every user but not for this one. what does it mean. i dont know much about mysite feature. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, you saw Profile pages for existing users? (http://localhost/my/Person.aspx?accountname=DOMAIN%5CVPupkin) The user should create your site itself or you can create programmatically with

```
SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(Site);
UP.UserProfileManager upm = new UP.UserProfileManager(context);
UP.UserProfile up = upm.GetUserProfile(LoginName);
up.CreatePersonalSite();
```

Comment: After User Profile Sync Personal Sites are created automatically, but if you created User Profile manually, then you should create Personal Site manually too.